# Characters like >, < and : after variables in Batch

Tags: variables, batch-file

So I'm trying to make a little input script.

The script will display the current path ending with a > and a space, then the user input will go after that.

```
set /p COMMAND=%~dp0 %=%
```

The problem is adding  the >. After the code to get the current directory, `%~dp0`, there should be a >. Problem is, when I use `%~dp0>`, batch throws an incorrect syntax error.

Is there any working fix for this? (Or a workaround).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `>` with a `^`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `>` with a caret.

```
set /p command=%~dp0^>
```

Comment: Sure, but you need a `^` before each special character.  `set /p var=%~dp0^<^|^:^|^>`.  This can be ugly, so if you have a lot of characters to escape it's better to use the quotes method in @rojo's answer

Answer (score 3):

Or just enclose the `"var=str"` pair in quotes.

```
set /P "command=%~dp0>"
```

By the way, you might want to consider using `%CD%` instead of `%~dp0`.  If the working directory is different from the script directory, there could be some confusion with `%~dp0`; whereas `%CD%` contains the current working directory.  [Here's a full list](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) of Windows' environment variables.